# How to create a SQL view from different tables with same column names?

Tags: sql-view

trying to create a view from few tables,
when I ran the query I get an error: column xxx duplicated.
well, it's true. I assumed that it will be represented as tbl1.xxx, tbl2.xxx
but apparently this is represented as xxx, xxx and thats why I get the error.
i have to say that it's a lot of columns so I don't want to name all the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aliasing the duplicate column names to something distinct is probably your best option here:

```
CREATE VIEW yourView AS (
    SELECT t1.xxx AS xxx_1, t2.xxx AS xxx_2, ...
    FROM table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id
)
```

The only other option which comes to mind, as you have suggested, would be to formally rename the similar columns in one/both of the tables.  But, this is draconian and you should not have to do such plumbing for something as simple as creating a view.

Comment: if im doing as u suggested- dont I need to name all the columns?
like: select tbl1.a,tbl1.b and so on just to get the option to rename tow columns?

Comment: Yes, that's right, however it is generally desirable to always list out the columns you want to appear in any query or view.  So, despite what you might think, my suggested approach is good practice.